# Regex that repeats two capturing groups indefinitely (or puts an or between two capturing groups)

Tags: regex, regex-group

I'm trying to capture this string with a regex:

'random words here [[word|another bit]] more random words [[another word|another]] more random words |'

The important thing is that it ends on a '|'. So any '|' within the regex must be within [[ ]]. I constructed a regex that captures '[[word|another bit]]', but the problem is that this group needs to be repeated indefinitely, with random words in between the group matching. Can I use an or between capturing groups?

Like ((random words regex) | ([[ ]] regex))*

?   it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: What language/tool are you using? From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood all the cases, but the following regex works for your example provided in Javascript:

```
/\[.*?\|.*?]]/g
```

You need to escape special characters with a backwards slash. Check out https://regex101.com/r/YgWrnM/1 for more details